# ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Scalars can be only used with projection

Tags: apache-pig

My input records:

```
4000001,Kristina,Chung,55,Pilot
4000002,Paige,Chen,74,Teacher
4000003,Sherri,Melton,34,Firefighter
4000004,Gretchen,Hill,66,Computer hardware engineer
4000005,Karen,Puckett,74,Lawyer
4000006,Patrick,Song,42,Veterinarian
4000007,Elsie,Hamilton,43,Pilot
4000008,Hazel,Bender,63,Carpenter
4000009,Malcolm,Wagner,39,Artist
4000010,Dolores,McLaughlin,60,Writer
4000011,Francis,McNamara,47,Therapist
4000012,Sandy,Raynor,26,Writer
4000013,Marion,Moon,41,Carpenter
4000014,Beth,Woodard,65,
4000015,Julia,Desai,49,Musician
4000016,Jerome,Wallace,52,Pharmacist
4000017,Neal,Lawrence,72,Computer support specialist
4000018,Jean,Griffin,45,Childcare worker
4000019,Kristine,Dougherty,63,Financial analyst
4000020,Crystal,Powers,67,Engineering technician
4000021,Alex,May,39,Environmental scientist
4000022,Eric,Steele,66,Doctor
4000023,Wesley,Teague,42,Carpenter
4000024,Franklin,Vick,28,Dancer
4000025,Claire,Gallagher,42,Musician
```

**Pig commands:**

```
cust = load '/input/custs' using PigStorage(',') as (custid:chararray, firstname:chararray, lastname:chararray,age:long,profession:chararray);
```

worked correctly

```
groupbyprofession = group cust by profession;
```

worked correctly

```
countbyprofession = foreach groupbyprofession generate group, COUNT(cust);
dump countbyprofession;
```

showing error:
**ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1000:** Error during parsing. Scalars can be only used with projection.

Comment: I didn't see any issue in the script and its looks fine. I just copied your input and script and it works fine for me.  Can you double check from your end?

Comment: I restart my system and it worked thanks Sivasakthi